# How to configure Apache Proxy to correctly return JAX-WS WSDL XSD location

Tags: apache, wsdl, jax-ws, weblogic12c, mod-proxy

I need to publish a JAX-WS webservice on a Weblogic application server behind a local Apache proxy. The Weblogic server is configured to listen to localhost requests only, and the Apache proxy redirects incoming requests to the application server via `http://myServer/myService` to `http://localhost:1234/myService` using `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` (there is a RewriteRule in effect to transfer al http: traffic to https:).

When I request the WSDL of my SOAP Service via `http://myServer/myService?wsdl`, I get the WSDL as I would expect, but the xsd schemaLocation part of the WSDL points to localhost, again as expected (since the webservice is effectively called from localhost):

```
<types>
  <xsd:schema>
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:1234/myService?xsd=1" namespace="http://myService.myCompany.com"/>
  </xsd:schema>
</types>
```

When I request the xsd by the schemaLocation xsd URL replacing localhost by the correct Server name, the xsd looks as I would expect. Since the localhost part is definitely wrong, I changed the Apache configuration to preserve the callers hostname by adding `ProxyPerserveHost On` to my httpd configuration file, the returned wsdl points to myServer, again as I would expect:

```
<types>
  <xsd:schema>
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://myServer:80/myService?xsd=1" namespace="http://myService.myCompany.com"/>
  </xsd:schema>
</types>
```

Again, retrieving the xsd from that URL works fine, the xsd is valid and looks as expected. When I try to create a SoapUI SOAP Project from the URL `http://myServer/myService?wsdl` I get an error `org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected end of file after null`

When I retrieve the same WSDL from an identical deployment on a Weblogic server without an Apache proxy and even if I call the service directly without the proxy on the original server, everything works fine.

How would I have to configure my Apache Proxy correctly to be able to use dynamic WSDL delivery and to return valid wsdl and xsd without having to manually create a wsdl file with embedded xsd?

Answer (score 0):

O.k., it seems I figured it out by myself...

The problem seemed to be the port. Originally, the xsd schemaLocation was given as `http://myServer:80`. After disallowing http: traffic to my deployment in the application server deployment configuration, the port was returned correctly as 443, which made everything else work correctly, too:

```
<types>
  <xsd:schema>
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://myServer:443/myService?xsd=1" namespace="http://myService.myCompany.com"/>
  </xsd:schema>
</types>
```